# SwiftUI: How to use .brightness ViewModifier as a gradient?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, brightness

I need to make the bottom (sometimes top) of my image to be a little bit brighter.

Currently I am using the code below to achieve this result, but it's not great -
I am using `LinearGradient` with `Color.clear` and `Color.white.opacity()`.

How can I modify the image with something like `LinearGradient` with `.brightness(0)` and `.brightness(1)`?

I want to use the `.brightness()` ViewModifier created by Apple, since the behaviour (output) of `.brightness(amount)` is **different** from the behaviour (output) of `.overlay { Color.white.opacity(amount) }`

```
import SwiftUI

struct White: View {
    @State private var amount = 0.5
    
    var body: some View {
        Image("Background")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .overlay {
                LinearGradient(colors: [Color.clear, Color.white.opacity(amount)], startPoint: .center, endPoint: .bottom)
            }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the output image what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom modifier by adopting `ViewModifier` protocol and achieve what you want.

See the following code where I have created `struct` Brightness. It contains four properties that will use to apply a gradient on view.

```
struct Brightness: ViewModifier {
    var start: UnitPoint
    var end: UnitPoint
    var startColor: Color
    var endColor: Color
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay {
                LinearGradient(colors: [startColor, endColor], startPoint: start, endPoint: end)
            }
    }
}
```

Then, create a modifier in the extension of View with the method and parameters respective to the brightness modifier. Check below code:

```
extension View {
    func brightness(startPoint: UnitPoint = .top, endPoint: UnitPoint = .bottom, startColor: Color = .white.opacity(0.7), endColor: Color = .white.opacity(0)) -> some View {
        modifier(Brightness(start: startPoint, end: endPoint, startColor: startColor, endColor: endColor))
    }
}
```

So, the above method will work as a modifier on any view. Assigned some default values to avoid unnecessary parameter values passing.

See the below code that illustrates the use of a custom modifier.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image("Career")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .brightness()
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Brightness - Top To Bottom]

You can vary the values of the parameters as you want.

```
.brightness(startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
```

**Output:**

[image: Brightness - Bottom To Top]

I hope this is the solution that you looking for. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However this solution still uses Color.white.opacity(). I was looking for something using .brightness() ViewModifier created by Apple, since the behaviour (output) of .brightness(amount) is **slightly different** from the behaviour of .overlay { Color.white.opacity(amount) } Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: By the way, if my question is not clear, please help me correct it.

Comment: .brightness is used for the entire view to set brightness. You can not default brightness view to achieve gradient things. If you still post and image of output, it will be better to answer for crowd.